# Web App for architectural plan upload and measure

Tags: web-apps, cad

I've got a planimetry of my house and a warehouse on paper.
I would like to scan them in JPEG, import them on my pc and measure them.
I'm looking for a website (web-app) where I can

- upload those tiff, jpeg or pdf files
- define a scale (measuring something of known measure to give a correct scale to the entire image)
- measure the rooms drawing polygons over them
- and print out the image with my measured polygons or send them at my email with the total area reported.

I can't find anything like this on the web. Is this kind of utility uncommon? Can anyone suggest a simple solution to measure my planimetries without installing any software?

Comment: Check out [Floorplanner](http://www.floorplanner.com/).  I haven't used it before, but it looks like it can do what you want.  Check out the "2.7 Tracing an existing drawing" section of their [manual](http://plus.floorplanner.com/forum/1531).